# Long Number Removing First Bit - Fast Way JAVA

Tags: java

I have a series of long numbers in a long array. I want to take each Long number and want to get the first bit of it and according to the first bit, I want to process the other bits. Like following pseudo code,

```
i = 1000000 ;
long[] a = new long[i];
for j = 0  to i
 do,
  get long lo = a[i];

  // get first bit of lo

  if first bit = 0
     print long number (by removing first bit) in file a1

  else 
     print long number (by removing first bit) in file a2
```

Can anybody help me, what is the fastest way to, "get the first bit of that long number" and "removing the first bit and get the number" ?

Comment: This doesn't look like java...

Comment: @DanW it's pseudo code it's mentioned in the question.

Comment: Do you mean the 'least valuable', or the 'most valuable' bit? (left or right when written in binary?)

Comment: @Hassan, sorry, I forgot to it is, 'most valuable' bit. like "011111", I want '0'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bit mask the number with 1.

```
long temp = a[i];
int bit = (temp >> 63) & 1;
```

this will shift the number over 63 places and bitwise and the number with 1. This will be 1 if the bit is 1 and 0 if the bit is 0.

if you want the lowest bit you don't need to shift

```
int bit = temp & 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, what I have to do, if I want to get number with out lowest bit (for example "1110" to "111").

Comment: the second one `int bit = temp & 1;` gets the lowest bit. If you want to remove the lowest bit just do a shift `temp = temp >>> 1;`

Answer (score 3):

twain249 beat me to the testing part, but here's the answer to the other part of your question:

```
long longWithoutTheFirstBit = a[i] & 0x7fffffff;
```

Answer (score 1):

long is an 8 byte number, so to get the first bit you can do

```
long l = ...
long firstBit = l & 0x80000000; // this will be 0 if the first bit is 0
```

Be aware that in two's complement, the first bit is a sign bit.

To get the number without the first bit you can do l - firstBit or you can do

long noFirstBit = l & 0x7FFFFFFF

Answer (score 1):

Get the first bit: `number >>> 63` -- notice three > signs -- that's for **unsigned** shift right!

Remove the first bit: `number & ~(1L << 63)`